# How to set "TabsStyle.Hidden" property on TabbedPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabs

In Xamarin.Forms, I'm using a `TabbedPage`, but I wanted the tab navigation to be hidden.

There is an enum `TabsStyle`, with following options:

- **Default:**  Tabs are placed and displayed according to system defaults.
- **Hidden:**   Tabs are hidden.
- **Icons:**    Tabs are shown as icons.
- **OnBottom:** Tabs are displayed at the bottom of the page.
- **OnNavigation:** Tabs are displayed when the user swipes from a screen edge.

But I can't seem to find any reference on where to set this property. Where do I set it? How to hide the tab navigation on a TabbedPage?

Comment: as best as I can tell, TabsStyle is just used internally by a few renderers

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the TabsStyle is used only by [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/PlatformConfiguration/macOSSpecific/TabsStyle.cs) for macOS.